# Max edit distance and suggestion based on word frequency

Tags: c#, c++, nlp, spell-checking, hunspell

I need a spell checker with the following specification:

- Very scalable.
- To be able to set a maximum edit distance for the suggested words.
- To get suggestion based on provided words frequencies (most common word first).

---

I took a look at Hunspell:
I found the parameter MAXDIFF in the man but doesn't seem to work as expected. Maybe I'm using it the wrong way

file **t.aff**:

```
MAXDIFF 1
```

file **dico.dic**:

```
5  
rouge  
vert  
bleu  
bleue  
orange
```

-

```
NHunspell.Hunspell h = new NHunspell.Hunspell("t.aff", "dico.dic");
List<string> s = h.Suggest("bleuue");
```

returns the same thing `t.aff` being empty or not:

```
bleue
bleu
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We decided to use `Apache Solr`, which exactly fulfills our needs.
http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SpellCheckComponent#spellcheck

Answer (score 0):

A maxdiff of one should return a few, but still can return more than one.

Even a maxdiff of zero *can* give more than a single result, but it should lower the change. It depends on the [n-gram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-gram). Try a maxdiff of zero less results, but this still doesn't guarantee you will get a single suggestion.

For your requirement to sort on the most frequent word, the [Google ngram corpus](http://googleresearch.blogspot.com/2006/08/all-our-n-gram-are-belong-to-you.html) is publicly available.